# Google OAuth tokeinfo not returning user details

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin

I am using Google OAuth Playground to generate tokens to test my REST API. I enter profile,email in scope text field of playground. It returns the id_token and use this id_token to get userinfo from link 
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token as stated here in documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth.
But it doesn't return any userinfo in JSON.

Comment: Do you have permissions? (ie proper scopes)

Comment: Yes. I am getting token from oauth playground with correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

User info can be retrieved using the below endpoint using your access ID.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo

What you are doing is retrieving token info using `id_token` which is different from retrieving the user's info (although some returned data overlaps).